# Paypal Sandbox Orders API - Funds not being added to balance after capture

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have a Paypal Smart Payments Button integration set up that pretty much exactly follows the format given on [the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/). It creates the order through the JS SDK, and then has an actions.order.capture method in the onApprove callback, like so:

```
paypal.Buttons({
createOrder: (data, actions) => {
    return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
                value: get_gross()
            }
        }],
        application_context: {
            brand_name: '...',
            shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
        }
    })
},

onApprove: (data, actions) => {
    actions.order.capture().then((details) => {
        return fetch('/paypal/donate', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                ...
            })
        }).then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                ...
            } else {
                ...
            }
        });
    });
}
}).render('#donate_button_container');
```

The problem is that once this flow is complete, I get the response back in the site backend showing that the order has completed, same as on the Paypal sandbox dashboard which shows the money has been deducted, but in the sandox facilitator account the funds arent appearing in the balance. They show as completed transactions, but the balance doesnt update. Both accounts are verified so should be able to both send and receive funds.

Have I missed a step somewhere with how payment capturing works? As far as I can tell from the docs the payment should be captured into the balance instantly, which is what I need to happen as my backend has to split the payment between two other accounts after this completes, which it currently fails to do due to insufficient funds errors.

Thanks!!

**EDIT:** One of my team members has found that setting the status to 'Shipped' in the paypal backend causes the funds to clear, which shouldnt be happening as shipping_preference was set to NO_SHIPPING. Is there anyway to override this/set the order to shipped through the API?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your activity log where these transactions show up but aren't reflected in the balance?

Comment: @DrewAngell https://www.dropbox.com/s/ozoqc7gp0nurnq2/paypal2.PNG?dl=0 <-- screenshot here, its a little bit harder to understand the issue now though for reasons i've edited the post with. A team member found that setting the payments to "shipped" in the backend clears the funds, which isnt expected since we set the order context to no_shipping. He's since cleared a bunch of the test payments and it's showing a balance now